# Add linkedIn Connections as Friends in My Own website using JSAPI

Tags: javascript, connection, linkedin-api, profile

I am developing a site in which I have used LinkedIn JavaScript API for creating account and add LinkedIn Connections as Friends.

I have got all the connections from the LinkedIn on my page,
but how can I add them as friends with each other.

I am struggling with this
please help if anyone can,

Comment: Is this even possible? Are you trying to make accounts, that are not your own, friends with each other?

Comment: I think you need a little more context in your question. To clarify: You want to add LinkedIn connections as friends on your own website. Then you want to a code that will make everyone friends with one and other? So like one BIG web of friends?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the documentation for the invitation API of Linkedin [here](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/invitation-api).

However, after reading the documentation, you will see that whoever uses your application to make a new connection will be redirected in Linkedin with the corresponding "invitation message" that is sent on each invitation, so that he verifies the message (or even change it before making the invitation). Thus, your application will not be capable to create new connections, without the person that initiates the connection be informed about that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 and I hope you get my +50 bounty. ;)

Comment: There are no other answers so I awarded you my +50 bounty. Thanks and best regards.